# Prevent click event on child, produce pop up triggered by parent

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have lis containing anchor tags among other things. Click on li opens up a modal window and clicking on child anchor tag deletes the li(this is what is desirable). But clicking on anchor tag triggers click event on li and opens up the modal window. How to get around this problem. I even tried event.stopPropagation, but even that didn't stop modal opening.

Thanx in advance!!

Comment: We can't help you unless you post your code in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are tow ways to avoid event propagation:

1. stop event propagation in the anchor click event
2. check for the target element on the li click event

To delete/replace the parent li clicking on the child anchor you can you the replaceWith.

```js
$(function () {
  $('li').click(function(e) { // if event is originated from li OK
    if ($(e.target).is('li')) {
      alert('open modal');
    }
  });
  
  
  $('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //e.stopPropagation();    // stop propagation
    $(this).parent('li').replaceWith($(this));  // remove parent li
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>


<li>Coffe
    <a href="http://www.googlee.com">Anchor</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

To have **anchor element** not doing its basic thing(going on desired url) you'll have to use jQuery's [event.preventDefault](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) method.

The basic use:

```
$('a').click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
});
```